# how to use a function from a other object inside new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get this work but It wont work so how to I call the function thats created in 1 object in side a different object?

```
 // part of the plugin

 Plugin.prototype = {

     objectStart: function(){
        function runSomeCode(){
           alert('yeah');
        }
     },

     objectEnd: function(){
        runSomeCode();//not working
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're *really* trying to do. `runSomeCode` is scoped to the function attached to `objectStart`; there's zero ways to access it the way you've written it. What's your goal?

Comment: You're gonna have to externalize it. Define the target JS function outside the outer object. Call it from start and end.

Comment: hmmm well than im going to move that function outside the scope if there is no way to do this. Thanks

Comment: WHich is the "different object" you're talking about? There's only one object in the question, the object that you assign to `Plugin.prototype`. `objectStart` and `objectEnd` are properties of that object, they aren't different objects.